# Want support in polkadot.js/api

Tags: kusama, staking

I am trying to call api.query.staking.erasTotalStake in polkadot.js.

Docs: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/storage/#erastotalstakeu32-u128

Which value can be parameter? Docs says u32. Is it block height?

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-leakey-6jzrz9?file=/index.js
This is my working code sandbox, I am just getting response 0.

How can I get another response beyond 0, and check if this api works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is the era you want to query.
The current value is 3728.

You can check values directly with https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.polkadot.io#/chainstate.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your comment. I was able to get response. One more question. How can I get human readable value from response? I am getting <BN: 4f56b6cd0ff56b83>

Comment: You can use `toString()`, `toHuman()` or `toBigInt()` to get a more friendly value.

More info at https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/types.basics/

Comment: Hi, I am trying api.query.staking.eraStakers on https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Fkusama-rpc.polkadot.io#/chainstate which you sent.
However, I cannot select any AccountId32, or type. I can type era. How can I select account?

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are trying to do.  

From the polkadiot.js.org/apps, you need to enable the `include option` option, then slect/type an account address.  

For example, era `3728` and account `JCghFN7mD4ETKzMbvSVmMMPwWutJGk6Bm1yKWk8Z9KhPGeZ` are valid inputs.